# Javascript while loop explanations

Tags: javascript, while-loop

This is my first post here so pls be kind to my noob question.

I have a simple while statement in javascript and i can't understand the result. 
The code:

```js
    var a = 0;
    while (a < 10) {
     console.log(a);
     a++;
    }
```

The result is:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
9

So my question is: why is the number 9 printed two times?

Comment: I guess I've just answered the question ))

Comment: @georg No you didn't. Snippet output is empty.

Comment: Results are displayed in the console, not in the browser.

Comment: If you run this from the dev console, you may be seeing the `console.log` output followed by the result of the last expression, which is `9`.

Comment: I get 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate the expression in the **console** (not in the browser like the snippet you posted), it will not only dump the information passed to `log` but also the last evaluated value of the overall expression.